# Since no current flows, the voltage is 0?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, homework-and-exercises

[image]

I didn't understand that ,

"Since no current flows in the ammeter the potentioal difference is 0 "
How did they conclude that?

I made this example

[image]
So i made this example in paints , (R square means resistor , just a different notation)

So since I=0 the potential difference is 0

So , no current flows between A and B :Va-Vb=0 which means that E = 0 which is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beginning statement is incorrect or, at best, misleading.

There *could*, in fact, be a current through the ammeter and it would still be the case the potential at $C$ equals the potential at $D$.

Let me explain.  The voltage across an (ideal) ammeter is *zero*.  Thus, with the ammeter in the circuit as pictured, it is *given* that $V_C = V_D$ - the presence of the ammeter allows no other possibility.

Now, consider the circuit *without the ammeter present*.  If it is then the case that $V_C = V_D$, then it easy to show that one can place an ammeter between $C$ and $D$ and there will be zero current through.

However, if $V_C \ne V_D$ when the ammeter is removed, there *will* be a current through the ammeter when connected between $C$ and $D$.

In summary, the opening statement should be clarified as so:

> Since no current flows in the ammeter, the electric potential of point
>   $C$ is the same as the electric potential of point $D$ *when the
>   ammeter is removed*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this is the Wheatstone bridge (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge).

Imagine that in the top diagram the $V$ is $10~V$ and all the resitances of the resistors are the equal to each other - say $100  ~\Omega$ each.

Let us say the potential at E and F is $0 ~V$, and at A and B is $10~ V$ - because the resistances are all equal the potential at both C and D will be $5 ~V$  and like in the diagram you drew with paint the difference in potential between points C and D will be $0~V$ and $I$ will be zero. (The two pairs of resistors act as potential dividers - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider)

now it turns out if the fraction $R_1 \over R_2$ is different to the fraction $R_2 \over R_4$ then the potentials at C and D will be different and a current will flow.

(The Wheatstone bridge was the way to measure resistances before we had multimeters - if you have known resitances at $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_3$ (or any three of the four) you can find $R_4$ (or whichever the fourth one is) with

${R_1 \over R_2} = {R_2 \over R_4}$